# Duration of stay in Schengen area is shorter than tour - what to do?

Tags: visas, schengen

I got 60 days Schengen visa 23.06.2014 to 23.08.2014, issued by the Portugese Embassy in Delhi. However, duration of stay is shown as only for 15 days, but I need 19 days to complete my tour, in terms of my air tickets, which I had submitted along with my visa application. What should I do?

Comment: Did you travel to the Schengen area recently?

Answer (score 5):

“Duration of stay” really means what it seems to mean, you definitely should not stay 19 days in the Schengen area with a 15-day visa, no matter its period of validity. If you did submit an application for a 19-day trip with all required documents, I can only surmise the consulate made a mistake. The only solution I can think of is calling the Portuguese consulate and ask if they could amend/extend the visa. Canceling their own visa and issuing a new one is always possible but the Portuguese authorities are the only ones that could do that and you can't count on being able to enter and leave the Schengen area without problems if you did not secure a visa covering the whole trip in advance.

Comment: What if the OP chooses to "overstay" for 4 days?

Comment: @AditySomani In theory, he shouldn't be let in at all (border guards occasionally check return tickets). If he does overstay, he might be liable for a fine, depending on local law. He might also have difficulties when applying for a visa again. He might also get lucky.